# How to parse deserialized JSON object back into arrays?

Tags: json, vb.net, winforms, dictionary, json.net

I have successfully been able to serialize an entire class of properties (array, vectors of strings, integers, doubles).  Deserialize also works, but I need a way to parse the returned object into the various arrays, and then set these equal to the four arrays of the same dimension.

Before, when I was using BinaryFormatter, I could simply declare `mydeser As Object`, deserialize into `mydeser`, and then pick off the arrays directly by using e.g. `readarray = mydeser.array`.

I did notice that a JObject is a type of dictionary, but I don't know what the keys would be or the values, which are some sort of jsonToken.

I tried using:

```
For each kvp as KeyValuePair(String, jsonToken) in myser
Next
```

but an exception was thrown. So is there a way to maybe use a key, and then the JObject's values directly into the arrays, using maybe `readarray = mydeser("array")` -- assuming `mydeser` is a dictionary?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ser As New testSer
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class testSer
    Public Property array As Double(,)
    Public Property vector As Double()
    Public Property strVec As String()
    Public Property IntVec As Integer()
    Sub New()
        serdeser()
    End Sub
    Sub serdeser()
        Dim r As New Random
        ReDim array(1000, 1000)
        ReDim vector(1000)
        ReDim strVec(1000)
        ReDim IntVec(1000)
        For i = 1 To 1000
            vector(i) = r.NextDouble
            strVec(i) = "A"
            IntVec(i) = r.Next(1, 100)
            For j = 1 To 1000
                array(i, j) = r.NextDouble
            Next
        Next

        Dim jsonSerializer As New JsonSerializer

        Dim stream As FileStream = File.Create("D:\test")
        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(stream)
        Dim jsonWriter As New JsonTextWriter(writer)
        jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, Me)
        writer.Close()

        Dim stream1 As FileStream = File.Open("D:\test", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(stream1)
        Dim jsonTextReader As New JsonTextReader(reader)
        Dim mydeser As Linq.JObject
        mydeser = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader)

        Dim readarray(1000, 1000) As Double
        Dim readvector(1000) As Double
        Dim readstrVec(1000) As String
        Dim readIntVec(1000) As Integer

        Dim mystr = DirectCast(mydeser.First, Linq.JProperty)
        'readarray = mydeser.array <--need to assign "array" back into readarray
        'readvector = mydeser.vector
        'readstrVec = mydeser.strvec
        'readarray = mydeser.intvec

        reader.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions, considering that this is a test class:

- Your serialization procedure is mostly correct. It's preferable to declare the Stream objects with a `Using` statement, thus in case of an exception, these objects are implicitly disposed.
- The deserialization becomes quite simple if you just specify the Type to deserialize to. The Type is represented by the Type of your class. You can just write (see the sample code):

  ```
  Dim myObject = [JsonSerializer].Deserialize(Of [MyObjectType])([JsonTextReader])
  ```
- You don't need a FileStream, StreamWriter / StreamReader already use a FileStream internally on their own. StreamWriter creates the file if it doesn't exist.
- The StreamReader is initialized explicitly with `Encoding.UTF8`: it's the default, it's simply a remainder that this is the Encoding used and that the file is saved without BOM signature.
- Call `Close()` on the JsonTextWriter before you exit the `Using` block. The behavior is determined by the `AutoCompleteOnClose` property, set to `True` by default and it's safer.
- When deserializing, set the JsonTextReader's `FloatParseHandling` property to `FloatParseHandling.Double` or `FloatParseHandling.Decimal`. `Double` is actually the default, just keep this in mind, in case you need to handle Decimal values, which are otherwise deserialized as `Double`.
- The lower bound of arrays is `0`, not `1`
- Make your `Random` object a static Field. This ensures a better functionality (or, it lets the class function properly, if you want).

In the modified sample class, I've overloaded the Constructor: passing `True`, will call the `Build()` method that fills the class object with random data.
Passing `False`, generates an empty object.

It's not necessary to make a copy of the deserialized values, you can generate a new class object from the JsonSerializer directly. For example:

```
Dim jsonPath = "d:\test.json"

' Passing True to the Constuctor, calls the Build() method
Dim serTest = New SerializationTest(True)
' Serialize all property values to the specified File
serTest.Serialize(jsonPath)

' Creates a new SerializationTest objects and fills it
' deserializing the JSON previously saved calling Serialize() 
Dim serTest2 = New SerializationTest(False).Deserialize(jsonPath)
```

You can compare the two objects, `serTest` and `serTest2`
In case a copy is needed, see at the bottom.

**Modified class**:

```
Public Class SerializationTest
    Private Shared rnd As New Random()

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(False)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(useBuilder As Boolean)
        If useBuilder Then Build()
    End Sub

    Public Property DblArray As Double(,)
    Public Property DblVector As Double()
    Public Property StringVector As String()
    Public Property IntVector As Integer()

    Public Sub Serialize(jsonPath As String)
        Using stream As New StreamWriter(jsonPath)
            Dim jWriter As New JsonTextWriter(stream)
            Dim serializer As New JsonSerializer()
            serializer.Serialize(jWriter, Me)
            jWriter.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Function Deserialize(jsonPath As String) As SerializationTest
        Using reader As New StreamReader(jsonPath, Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim jReader As New JsonTextReader(reader) With {
                .FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Double
            }
            Dim serializer As New JsonSerializer()
            Dim deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(Of SerializationTest)(jReader)
            jReader.Close()
            Return deserialized
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Sub Build()
        ReDim DblArray(1000, 1000)
        ReDim DblVector(1000)
        ReDim StringVector(1000)
        ReDim IntVector(1000)
        For i = 0 To 1000
            DblVector(i) = rnd.NextDouble()
            StringVector(i) = $"A{i}"
            IntVector(i) = rnd.Next(1, 101)
            For j = 0 To 1000
                DblArray(i, j) = rnd.NextDouble()
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

If you, for some reason, want to copy the deserialized values to the initialized, but *empty*, class object, then change the method like this:

```
Public Sub Deserialize(jsonPath As String)
    Using reader As New StreamReader(jsonPath, Encoding.UTF8)
        Dim jReader As New JsonTextReader(reader) With {
            .FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Double
        }
        Dim serializer As New JsonSerializer()
        Dim deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(Of SerializationTest)(jReader)
        jReader.Close()

        Me.DblArray = deserialized.DblArray
        Me.DblVector = deserialized.DblVector
        Me.StringVector = deserialized.StringVector
        Me.IntVector = deserialized.IntVector
        deserialized = Nothing
    End Using
End Sub
```

And change the code that fills it in:

```
Dim serTest = New SerializationTest(False)
serTest.Deserialize(jsonPath)
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Jimi for the suggestions and edits.  BTW, I know C# and VB.NET arrays are zero-based, but I jump to FORTRAN a lot, which is not zero-based.  I do want to test your latter code section which copies deserialized values into the class object, since I don't want to increase the decorations with looping but rather straightforwardly fill arrays.  Does binary matter, since it was originally used for piping the I/O to disk and back?  I am not sure if binary reads/writes of the (soon to be deprecated) BinaryFormatter are faster than NewtonSoft.Json via streamreader/streamwriter?

Comment: All files are Binary *in nature*, the fact that we see *text* is just an interpretation of the content. Of course using a StreamReader can be slower than just reading byte values without an encoder, a little more if we need to read line by line (seeking the line terminators). Otherwise, it's just a FileStream (StreamReader/Writer of course use a FileStream internally, that's why I wrote that is not necessary to explicitly open one) -- BinaryFormatter performs a lot of checks related to assembly compatibility that are not necessary, one of the reasons why nobody uses it anymore.